# Prevent bash from forwarding stdin to stderr

Tags: objective-c, c, bash, shell, stream

I'm trying to implement a simple terminal GUI using bash's interactive mode. I successfully invoked bash, get its **stdout** and print everything to a text view. I forward the user input from the text view to bash's **stdin**, to be able to run commands. It works great, except I don't get any error messages.

However, when I proceeded to print bash's **stderr** to my text view, I noticed something strange. In addition to now receiving error messages, bash seems to pass everything from **stdin** to **stderr**. Because of this, every character I type is printed twice (once normally because I enter it, and once because I print everything from **stderr**).

It also seems to print the prompt via **stderr** (`bash-3.2$`). Is this the expected behavior? Can this be suppressed?

I also tried to just capture use input (and not let the user type directly into the text view) and rely on bash to print the user input. This is almost working, except the order of the output via **stdout** and **stderr** is random:

If I type a command like `echo test` and hit enter, sometimes I get this: 
(the second `test` is the output, I didn't type `testtest`)

```
bash-3.2$ echo testtest
bash-3.2$
```

Sometimes I get:

```
bash-3.2$ echo test
bash-3.2$ test
```

The order in which I receive the final `\n`, the output and the next `bash-3.2$` is obviously mixed up.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but reminds me of the old DOS `@echo off`

Comment: How are you invoking bash?  I'm not sure what you're actually implementing.

Comment: It looks like buffering issue to me. `bash` does perform stdin echo to stderr so that user on a standard terminal emulator sees what he's typing. You probably get some strange buffering on stdout and stderr which prevents you from reading characters straight away as they are sent from bash. But… I don't know objective-c, so I cannot help you more than that.

Comment: I'm using [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to invoke bash. It allows me to use `NSFileHandle` objects or C file descriptors to read/write stdout/in/err. I'm trying to implement a simple terminal window on my own (to be used as part of an app later).

Comment: @liori I'm seeing what I type right away. But once I hit enter to execute a command 3 things should be printed in this order: 1. the `\n` I just typed via stderr 2. the output of my command via stdout 3. `bash-3.2$` via stderr. But the order is mixed up. Are stdout/err via file descriptor read/write functions buffered? I'm reading everything as soon as it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to read stdout and stderr in the "correct" order, because there is no notion of order between different pipes.  But you can ensure that both are sent to the same pipe (i.e. same file descriptor) instead of having each one go to a separate pipe.  To do that, look on the options of whatever you use to start the bash subprocess; or maybe start a command line like `bash -c 'bash 2>&1'`.

Comment: Why did I not think of this?... Thanks a lot, this seems to work.